# Issue during the installation of dual boot windows 10and ubuntu 24.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

So I decided to finally make the decision to switch to Ubuntu today and to set up a dual boot Ubuntu Windows 10 set up. I partition my C Drive to install Ubuntu on and create an install medium. I do the installation and when it's time to choose ”install along with windows” but it doesn't appear. Any advice? The question got locked, fix did not work. I should add, my windows copy isn't activated, is that needed?

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04.1 will probably be ready in July 2024....You will have to wait for a while  ;-) Apart from that: no, windows activation should not be necessary to dual boot. windows should however be properly shut down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: "C" is only "C" in Windows, and it's usually the OS partition, so you cannot install Ubuntu to "C"...  You need **unpartitioned free space** to get the automated "install alongside Windows" option to show up reliably.

Answer (score 0):

You meant 20.04.1 ? :) Windows need not be activated for this. Hope you have shrunk C: and created unallocated space on the hard drive. If there is enough unallocated space it should show ”install along with windows”. If still not showing then may be you can try "Something else" option (hope it is displayed), but that is a bit advanced. But can be done with a bit of effort.